# probability: choose 2r shoes from n pairs of shoes

Tags: probability-theory, combinations

A closet contains n pairs of shoes. If 2r shoes are chosen at random (2r<n), then we know that there are $2^{2r} {n\choose 2r}$ different cases in the event "there are no matching pairs in our selected sample". Now consider a different number ${2n\choose 1}\times {2n-2\choose 1}\times \dots {2n-2(r-1)\choose 1}$, is there an event that contain this number of different cases? Intuitively describe such an event.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you thought about it ? Tell us your intuition.

Comment: [Counting in two ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)#:~:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20double%20counting%2C%20also,the%20size%20of%20one%20set.)

Comment: @trueblueanil Thanks! This is helpful.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint **1**: Imagine pairs of shoes lined up as shown

$A \;B \;C \;D \;E \;F \;G \;H \;I \;J \;K \;L ...$

$A \;B \;C \;D \;E \;F \;G \;H \;I \;J \;K \;L ...$

What did you do in the first case, and what are you doing *that is different* in the second ?

Hint **2**: Take it that you are drawing $6$ shoes from the $12$ pairs

> You should be able to see that with the first formula, you are just *selecting* $6$ non-matching shoes, whereas with the second formula, you are *arranging* them in all possible ways. If you couldn't get it by intuition, verify by computations !

Comment: Thanks! This completely solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to be of help !